# Mongo - JS - How to convert a BSON/JSON object to XML

Tags: javascript, xml, json, mongodb, bson

While using JS scripting with the mongo-shell API, how do I convert a JSON/BSON object into a XML string.

I would probably write the XML string to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I grabbed the json2xml.js from here:

http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/json2xml.js

Then I saved it to the same folder as my mongo shell binary for convenience (so I didn't have to specify the full path.  Here are the results:

```js
> load("json2xml.js")
> db.bar.insert({"_id" : 123, foo : 1, x : "example"})
> db.bar.findOne()
{ "_id" : 123, "foo" : 1, "x" : "example" }
> json2xml(db.bar.findOne())
<_id>123</_id><foo>1</foo><x>example</x>
```

Now, you may need to extend this to deal with non-JSON types in MongoDB (see the [BSON Specification](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) page for details), but the basics are there.